# How to put Mac OS X wireless adapter in monitor mode

Tags: networking, osx, wifi

I'm searching for a equivalent of "iwconfig eth0 mode Monitor" in Mac OS.

From man iwconfig mode Monitor does the following:

"the node is not associated with any cell and passively monitor all packets on the frequency"

Answer (score 42, accepted):

What you're looking for is `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport`. It's a binary command, which I've symlinked into `/usr/local/bin/` for convenience.

Creating Symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport /usr/local/bin/airport
```

Example of sniffing in monitor mode:

```
sudo airport en1 sniff 1
```

This sniffs on channel 1 and saves a *pcap* capture file to `/tmp/airportSniffXXXXXX.pcap` (where XXXXXX will vary). You can view this with `tcpdump -r <filename>` or by opening it in `wireshark`.

To search for active channels nearby that you can sniff, run this:

```
sudo airport en1 -s
```

Although you can *capture* any traffic, you can only effectively *read* if the network is open or you have the encryption key.

Comment: It Works. Just a side note, the capture file extension is `.cap` and not `.pcap` as described. (OS X Mavericks 10.9)

Comment: this works in yosemite as well

Comment: very old solution and still today this works. 
tried with Catalina and this works. 
Thanks. Cheers.

Comment: Is sudo necessary? `-s` & `sniff` work without sudo on Big Sur 11.0.1.

Comment: @TeddyC This question was answered in 2012. It naturally doesn't cover Big Sur, released in 2020.

Comment: does it work with M1 processors?

Comment: @DarkSkull Yep.

Answer (score 17):

You can also do it via the GUI if that is easier for you.

In Mavericks:

- Search Spotlight (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>) for "Wireless
  Diagnostics"
- When the application opens, press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> or go to Window > Utilities to open the Utilities Window
- Click on the Frame Capture Tab
- Rename the output .wcap file to .pcap for use with Eye P.A.

Comment: Woah, Narnia! I didn't even know this existed!

Answer (score 10):

Pass the -I flag to tcpdump or tshark (wireshark command-line utility).

For example, to save everything from radiotap headers down to the application layer packets to a file named 'save.pcap':

```
tcpdump -Ini en0 -w save.pcap
```

Or to examine probe request 802.11 management frames live:

```
tshark -Ini en0 -s 256 type mgt subtype probe-req
```

Note, one OS X you will have to run the commands as root or grant yourself permission to access the kernel's packet filters:

```
sudo chmod 0644 /dev/bpf*
```

Answer (score 1):

`sudo tcpdump -Ii en0 > sniff`

Answer (score -1):

by default on OSX en0 is your ethernet port, while en1 is your airport

try:

```
iwconfig en1 mode monitor
```

Comment: There's no such command on Mac OS X.

Comment: strange, I just ran it... and it worked... and thanks for changing the interface names, forgot about that

Comment: You must have obtained it from somewhere else, it's not part of Mac OS X.

Comment: yeah, pretty sure you're right

Comment: "by default on OSX en0 is your ethernet port" If you *have* an Ethernet port.  My MacBook Pro has no Ethernet port; en0 is the AirPort interface, and, if I plug in a Thunderbolt-to-Ethernet adapter, it becomes en2.

Comment: iwconfig is a Linux command; are you sure you typed that command on a Mac running OS X and, if so, where did you get the iwconfig program?